# How to attach new HttpClient to asyncore loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, asyncore

I've basic asyncore HttpClient :

```
class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, path):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect( (host, 80) )
```

I want to run one instance and after starting asyncore event loop run another client and attach to that loop.

```
client = HTTPClient('www.example.org', '/')
asyncore.loop()
client2 = HTTPClient('www.example2.org', '/')
```

How to attach new client ? Can I use greenthread for start eventloop and then start new client ?